# Сколько ранее упорядоченных элементов в массиве? (Сортировка вставкой)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Каково количество упомянутых *ранее упорядоченных элементов* в массиве при сортировке вставкой?

> Сортировка вставками (англ. Insertion sort) — алгоритм сортировки, в
>   котором элементы входной последовательности просматриваются по одному,
>   и каждый новый поступивший элемент размещается в подходящее место
>   среди ранее упорядоченных элементов[1]. Вычислительная сложность —
>   O(n^2).

Сколько *раннее упорядоченных элементов*?

Comment: переформулируйте вопрос. На каком шаге или когда? После окончания сортировки - все. Сколько на предыдущем шаге - ну зависит от номера шага

Comment: Сколько уже просмотрено - столько уже ранее упорядоченных. На i-том шаге алгоритма будет i ранее упорядоченных элементов.

Answer (score 2):

> Сортировка вставками (англ. Insertion sort) — алгоритм сортировки, в котором элементы входной последовательности просматриваются по одному, и каждый новый **`k`-й** поступивший элемент размещается в подходящее место среди ранее упорядоченных **`k-1`** элементов[1].

Так понятнее? :)

Смотрите - когда вы вставляете `k`-й элемент, предыдущие уже стоят в порядке. Сколько этих предыдущих? Правильно, `k-1`...